# HD I/O Error On Certain Directories

Tags: hard-drive

Running windows 7, I have an HD that crashed, and I'm using a SATA to USB connector to connect the bad HD to my computer to try and recover files.  Some directories I can easily connect to, while others say I/O error, although the directory is visible itself.

Any software out there to help me recover the files that have that error?  Or another method other than sending it to a pro?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on exactly why it crashed and how bad - BUT - you might have some success with a tool like SpinRite 6. It's capable of recovering SOME data from "crashed" but not yet entirely dead drives.